# Dimension of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ and Diff$(M)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, lie-algebras, global-analysis

For a smooth closed Manifold $M^n$(of dimension $n$), if $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ denotes the set of all vector fields on the manifold $M$ then we can say that $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ form a vector space of some dimensions.

Now, let Diff$(M)$ denotes the group of all diffeomorphisms of $M$, so it is an *open submanifold*
of $C^{\infty}(M,M)$.

Also its given in [$43. 1$ of *Kriegl, Andreas; Michor, Peter W.*, [**The convenient setting of global analysis**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/434294), Mathematical Surveys and Monographs. 53. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). x, 618 p. (1997). [ZBL0889.58001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0889.58001).]
that

> *The Lie Algebra of the smooth **infinite dimensional Lie group** Diff$(M)$  is the convenient vector space $C_c^{\infty}(M \leftarrow TM)$ of **all smooth vector fields** on
> $M$ with compact support, equipped with the negative of the usual Lie bracket.*

Query:

If $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is the lie algebra of **infinite dimensional Lie group** Diff$(M)$,
so the lie algebra of Diff($M$)[i.e. $\mathfrak{X}(M)$] must also be **infinite dimensional vector space**, i.e. dim$\big(\mathfrak{X}(M)\big)=\infty$.

Now, is this statement correct or if not then please state the correct dimension of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ and where is my thinking wrong.

(P.S. Here $\mathfrak{X}(M)=C_c^{\infty}(M \leftarrow TM)=$ the space of all smooth sections of the bundle map $p: TM \longrightarrow M$)

Comment: You are likely misquoting your source. In particular, there is a confusion of compactly supported and general vector fields. Ditto for diffeomorphisms. Please, reread what you wrote.

Comment: If $C_{c}^{\infty}(M \leftarrow TM)$ is infinite dimensionsal then $C^{\infty}(M \leftarrow TM)$ will also be infinite dimensional as $C_{c}^{\infty}(M \leftarrow TM)$ $\subset$ $C^{\infty}(M \leftarrow TM)$

Comment: Of course. That was not the point of my comment.

Comment: Here for smooth compact manifolds compact support is the $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ only

Comment: @MoisheKohan But is it like for non compact manifold $M$ the Diff$(M)$ do not have manifold structure so we can't define its lie algebra. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your manifold is at least of dimension $1$, this space is infinite-dimensional. To see this, we can do the following construction:

Locally, a vector field is just a map
$$
X:U \to U \times \mathbb{R}^n
$$
for some open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Now, take a ball $B_{2\epsilon} \subset U$ of radius $2 \epsilon >0$ and consider a smooth, real valued bump function $\phi \in C^{\infty}(U)$ such that $\phi \geq 0$, $\phi=1$ on $B_{\epsilon}$ and $0$ outside of $B_{2 \epsilon}$. Now, we take any non-zero vector $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and define
$$
X_z:U \to U \times \mathbb{R}^n, x \mapsto (x,\phi z)
$$
and this extends to a smooth vector field outside of $U$ by setting it to the $0$-tangent vector.

We know that the space $C^{\infty}_c(B_{\epsilon})$ is infinite-dimensional. Hence we can construct infinitely many, linearly independent vector fields $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ by setting
$$
X_{z,\varphi}:U \to U \times \mathbb{R}^n, x \mapsto (x,\varphi \phi z)
$$
for $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(B_{\epsilon})$ and extending them by the $0$ vector on the compliment of $U$.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I want to ask if $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is infinite dimensional then I suppose dim$\big(T_p(M)\big)$ is also becoming $\infty$ but it should come as the dimension of manifold only and also what will be the dimension of $TM$ then.

Comment: At each point(!), the tangent space is finite dimensional. The dimension of $TM$ as manifold is $2n$. I also just constructed infinitely many, linearly independent vector fields $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$,

Comment: I added a bit more detail to the response and fixed 1 ambiguous notation.

Comment: But Can you prove *more generally* that $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ in infinite dimensional for a smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $n$. Also show that dim$(TM)=2n$.

Comment: @DeeponjitBose This is basically what this answer is about. More generally, the space of sections of a vector bundle over a manifold of positive dimension is infinite dimensional (same idea)

Comment: @Didier Thanks for your response

Comment: I think you are confusing the notion of the "dimension of a manifold" and the" dimension of the space of functions/vector fields of a manifold". Even in the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case, you have that the dimension is $n$, but e.g. the space $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is infinite-dimensional.